# LINQ SQL Attach, Update Check set to Never, but still Concurrency conflicts

Tags: sql, linq, sql-update

In the dbml designer I've set Update Check to Never on all properties. But i still get an exception when doing Attach: "An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not supported." This approach seems to have worked for others on here, but there must be something I've missed.

```
        using(TheDataContext dc = new TheDataContext())
        {
            test = dc.Members.FirstOrDefault(m => m.fltId == 1);
        }

        test.Name = "test2";

        using(TheDataContext dc = new TheDataContext())
        {
            dc.Members.Attach(test, true);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says exactly what is going wrong: You are trying to attach an object that has been loaded from another DataContext, in your case from another instance of the DataContext. Dont dispose your DataContext (at the end of the `using` statement it gets disposed) before you change values and submit the changes. This should work (all in one `using` statement). I just saw you want to attach the object again to the members collection, but it is already in there. No need to do that, this should work just as well:

```
using(TheDataContext dc = new TheDataContext())
{
    var test = dc.Members.FirstOrDefault(m => m.fltId == 1);
    test.Name = "test2";
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Just change the value and submit the changes.

## **Latest Update:**

*(Removed all previous 3 updates)*

My previous solution (removed it again from this post), found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122130146/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2007/12/25/117984.aspx) is dangerous. I just read this on a [MSDN article](https://web.archive.org/web/20080906122940/http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546187.aspx):

> "Only call the Attach methods on new
> or deserialized entities. The only way
> for an entity to be detached from its
> original data context is for it to be
> serialized. If you try to attach an
> undetached entity to a new data
> context, and that entity still has
> deferred loaders from its previous
> data context, LINQ to SQL will thrown
> an exception. An entity with deferred
> loaders from two different data
> contexts could cause unwanted results
> when you perform insert, update, and
> delete operations on that entity. For
> more information about deferred
> loaders, see Deferred versus Immediate
> Loading (LINQ to SQL)."

Use this instead:

```
// Get the object the first time by some id
using(TheDataContext dc = new TheDataContext())
{
    test = dc.Members.FirstOrDefault(m => m.fltId == 1);
}

// Somewhere else in the program
test.Name = "test2";

// Again somewhere else
using(TheDataContext dc = new TheDataContext())
{
    // Get the db row with the id of the 'test' object
    Member modifiedMember = new Member()
    {
        Id = test.Id,
        Name = test.Name,
        Field2 = test.Field2,
        Field3 = test.Field3,
        Field4 = test.Field4
    };
    
    dc.Members.Attach(modifiedMember, true);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

After having copied the object, all references are detached, and all event handlers (deferred loading from db) are not connected to the new object. Just the value fields are copied to the new object, that can now be savely attached to the members table. Additionally you do not have to query the db for a second time with this solution.

Comment: The code I posted was just a simplification. I need to be able to retrieve a Member from the db and then process it in detached mode. Then somewhere else a while later update that Member in the db. I can't do it all in the same datacontext.

Comment: That wont work, you have to stay in the same context, meaning you have to perform the attach and submitchanges operations on the same instance of TheDataContext from which you retrieved the object.

Comment: Was this what you were looking for? Sure, it isnt a very elegant solution, but you just cant switch contexts. Another way would be to just hold the datacontext in a static variable until the last submitchanges call.

Comment: Yes this is the approach I've been using before. But it seems kinda unnecessary to have to do a select before each update. So that's why I've been trying to use Attach instead. But I don't quite understand why Microsoft added this method at all since it's usability seem very limited.

Comment: Updated my answer one more time. The problem could be the references, still stored in the object. If my last solution works, you could leave deferred loading turned on.

Comment: @'But I don't quite understand why Microsoft added this method': Because of providing the ability of updating the db with information gathered from deserialized objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to attach entities from another datacontext.

The only thing that needs to be added to code in the first post is this:

```
dc.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false
```

But this is a drawback since deferred loading is very useful. I read somewhere on this page that another solution would be to set the Update Check on all properties to Never. This text says the same: http://complexitykills.blogspot.com/2008/03/disconnected-linq-to-sql-tips-part-1.html

But I can't get it to work even after setting the Update Check to Never.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function in my Repository class which I use to update entities

```
protected void Attach(TEntity entity)
{
   try
    {
       _dataContext.GetTable<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
       _dataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, entity);
    }
    catch (DuplicateKeyException ex) //Data context knows about this entity so just update values
    {
       _dataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, entity);
    }
}
```

Where TEntity is your DB Class and depending on you setup you might just want to do

```
_dataContext.Attach(entity);
```